# Menu buttons (text) overlapping when viewed on Android

Tags: android, html, css, scaling, overlap

I just did a complete redesign of my website, [hetoft.com](http://hetoft.com). I designed and coded everything in hand, only using Dreamweaver as help. It was my first time making a website with CSS based layout, and for all the trouble I had, this website was a great help. Thank you!

Anyway, on to my problem... My website is (AFAIK) looking fine in both IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari - also moble Safari. However, when scaling the window down a lot, the same thing Android does when you view the site on an Android phone, my menu points begin to overlap... The right menu overlaps with the left and it's a mess.

What do I do to fix this? I know I could just make the website a fixed width, but that kinda ruins my design and the whole point of a completely scalable website.

I hope you guys can help!

Regards,
Rasmus, hetoft.com

Comment: Also, I heard from a friend that my website is acting up on a phone running Windows Phone... So I hope one of you can tell me what's wrong there, too. :)

Comment: Is your website optimized for mobile devices?

Comment: @ I don't think so, no... How do I do that? It's looking fine on my iPhone, and I've made it so that if the user's device doesn't support Flash, it shifts to an HTML5 gallery.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting min-width in CSS ?

Comment: As simple as it sounds, it might be just what I was looking for! :) I'll definitely try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean on my X2, try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

It may also have to do with the 6 left-justified links and the 4 right-justified ones.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem... Those lines of code, do I simply add them to the <head> section of all the .html's?